# How to receive user information after logging in with vue.js in "Vuexy Admin Dashboard Template"

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I need help to get information from the user after logging. in Vuexy Vuejs Admin Dashboard Template.
With the current code, it now uses fake information.

please guide me.

[Look at this picture; The username is currently being read from a fake database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0KQz.jpg)

```js
// axios
import axios from 'axios'

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers:{
    common:{
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
```

Using the following code, we read the user name from the fake database.
activeUserInfo.displayName

```js
//ProfileDropDown.vue
<template>
  <div class="text-right leading-tight hidden sm:block">
    <p class="font-semibold">{{ activeUserInfo.displayName }}</p>
    <small>Available</small>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    activeUserInfo () {
      return this.$store.state.AppActiveUser
    }
  },
  methods: {
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Finally, the user's fake name is returned from here.
displayName: "Mary Adams",

```js
//state.js
/*=========================================================================================
  File Name: state.js
  Description: Vuex Store - state
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Item Name: Vuexy - Vuejs, HTML & Laravel Admin Dashboard Template
  Author: Pixinvent
  Author URL: http://www.themeforest.net/user/pixinvent
==========================================================================================*/

import navbarSearchAndPinList from '@/layouts/components/navbar/navbarSearchAndPinList'
import themeConfig, { colors } from '@/../themeConfig.js'

// /////////////////////////////////////////////
// Helper
// /////////////////////////////////////////////

// *From Auth - Data will be received from auth provider

const userDefaults = {
  uid         : 0,          // From Auth
  displayName : "Mary Adams", // From Auth
  about       : 'Dessert chocolate cake lemon drops jujubes. Biscuit cupcake ice cream bear claw brownie brownie marshmallow.',
  photoURL    : require('@assets/images/portrait/small/avatar-s-11.jpg'), // From Auth
  status      : 'online',
  userRole    : 'admin'
}

const getters = {
  // get_user : response.data.userInfo
}

const userInfoLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) || {}

// Set default values for active-user
// More data can be added by auth provider or other plugins/packages
const getUserInfo = () => {
  const userInfo = {}

  // Update property in user
  Object.keys(userDefaults).forEach((key) => {
    // If property is defined in localStorage => Use that
    userInfo[key] = userInfoLocalStorage[key] ?  userInfoLocalStorage[key] : userDefaults[key]
  })

  // Include properties from localStorage
  Object.keys(userInfoLocalStorage).forEach((key) => {
    if (userInfo[key] === undefined && userInfoLocalStorage[key] !== null) userInfo[key] = userInfoLocalStorage[key]
  })

  return userInfo
}


// Check if device is touch device
// This is used to remove perfect scrollbar from touch devices
// Using Dynamic components
const is_touch_device = () => {
  const prefixes = ' -webkit- -moz- -o- -ms- '.split(' ')
  const mq = function (query) {
    return window.matchMedia(query).matches
  }

  if ('ontouchstart' in window || window.DocumentTouch) {
    return true
  }

  // include the 'heartz' as a way to have a non matching MQ to help terminate the join
  // https://git.io/vznFH
  const query = ['(', prefixes.join('touch-enabled),('), 'heartz', ')'].join('')
  return mq(query)
}


// /////////////////////////////////////////////
// State
// /////////////////////////////////////////////

const state = {
  AppActiveUser           : getUserInfo(),
  bodyOverlay             : false,
  isVerticalNavMenuActive : true,
  is_touch_device         : is_touch_device(),
  mainLayoutType          : themeConfig.mainLayoutType || 'vertical',
  navbarSearchAndPinList,
  reduceButton            : themeConfig.sidebarCollapsed,
  verticalNavMenuWidth    : 'default',
  verticalNavMenuItemsMin : false,
  scrollY                 : 0,
  starredPages            : navbarSearchAndPinList['pages'].data.filter((page) => page.is_bookmarked),
  theme                   : themeConfig.theme || 'light',
  themePrimaryColor       : colors.primary,

  // Can be used to get current window with
  // Note: Above breakpoint state is for internal use of sidebar & navbar component
  windowWidth: null
}

export default state
```

Now I want to help you how I can read information from mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

you can simoly write method and call in in created hook.

```
//ProfileDropDown.vue
<template>
  <div class="text-right leading-tight hidden sm:block">
    <p class="font-semibold">{{ activeUserInfo.displayName }}</p>
    <small>Available</small>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data () {
    return {
       activeUserInfo: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getUserInfo () {
      try {
           const res = await axios.get('auth/me', {
               headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer token' }
           });
           this.activeUserInfo = res.data.user;
      } catch (e) {}
    }
  },
  async created() {
     await this.getUserInfo();
  }
}
</script>
```

If you want get data with store, you can use axios in state.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
...
const getUserInfo = () => {
  const userInfo = {}

  try {
      const res = await axios.get('auth/me', {
               headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer token' }
           });

      userInfo = res.data.user;
  } catch (e) {}

  return userInfo
}
...
```

And in your ProfileDropDown.vue file you can save your code

---

But in this case axios didn't work globally. If you want use it. you have to import axios in `main.js` file and use

```
//Create vue object
const http = axios.create({baseUrl: 'your base url'});

//set token for all reqeusts
http.interceptors.request.use(config => {
        const token: string | null = localStorage.get('token'); //or use what you want
        if (token) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
        }
        config.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
        config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        return config;
    },
    error => Promise.reject(error)
);

//Create globa axios object for Vue
Vue.prototype.$axios = http;


After that you don't need to import axios anywhere.
Instead of `axios` use `this.$axios` For ex:
...
const res = await this.$axios.get('auth/me')
this. activeUserInfo = res.data.user;
...
```

Comment: I feel this is a very accurate answer. But I am a beginner, please help with an example.

Comment: Thank you @farhod-nematov I easily log in with axios settings. But after logging in, I have trouble getting user information from the database. 
  baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' and headers:{
    common:{
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'
    }
  } 
  And I use this code to login: 
  login (email, pwd) {
    return axios.post('/api/auth/login', {
      email,
      password: pwd
    })
  },
  and token:
  refreshToken () {
    return axios.post('/api/auth/refresh-token', {accessToken: localStorage.getItem('accessToKen')})
  }

Comment: @msh I totally not understand your question